# 10.8.2 Finder windows: number of files in folder?

Tags: finder

I just upgraded to 10.8. Finder windows used to show me how many files were in a folder; where is that info now? Apple didn't get rid of it completely, did they?

Please tell me I don't have to manually count files now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the status bar was just hidden. You can show it by checking Show Status Bar from the View menu.